# Get a notification when questions get posted

Tags: python, web-scraping, stackexchange, beautifulsoup

I like to help people on StackOverflow, matter of fact nowadays it depends on how quick you are when answering question.
With that being said, I can't always keep a tab and an eye to refresh the browser to view new questions.

I made a very basic script to send me a notification (OSX) whenever there's a new question.

```
import requests, os, threading, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from timeloop import Timeloop
from datetime import timedelta

tl = Timeloop()

SE_REALTIME = "https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime"
WATCHED_TAG = "swift"
QUE_LI = []



# The notifier function
def notify(title, subtitle, message, link):
    t = '-title {!r}'.format(title)
    s = '-subtitle {!r}'.format(subtitle)
    m = '-message {!r}'.format(message)
    l = '-open {!r}'.format(link)
    os.system('terminal-notifier {}'.format(' '.join([m, t, s, l])))

def fetch():
    # The SOUP
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(SE_REALTIME).content, "html.parser")

    # List of Questions with the sid: Stackoverflow.com
    li = soup.find_all('div', {'data-sid': 'stackoverflow.com'})

    # Loop Through
    for child in li:
        id = child['class'][2]
        all_tags = child.find("span", attrs={'class': 'realtime-tags'}).text.strip()
        tags = all_tags.split()
        if WATCHED_TAG in tags:
            if id not in QUE_LI: 
                question = child.find("a", attrs={'class': 'realtime-question-url realtime-title'})
                QUE_LI.append(id)
                notify(title = 'New Question {}'.format(' '.join([WATCHED_TAG])),
                subtitle = 'Stackoverflow.com',
                message  = question.text.strip(),
                link = question['href'])



@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=2))
def fetch_questions_every_2s():
    fetch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tl.start(block=True)
```

Ok, This code works well. But I'm looking for:

1. A way to listen for changes on the div tree (without making a request every 2 second)
2. Less code.

Dependencies:

```
Terminal-Notifier
BeautifulSoup
TimeLoop
Requests
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I trimmed your question description a little bit in order to make it more succinct. If you don't agree with this, feel free to [revert these changes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/229875/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from using the SE API (for example via some module like [py-stackexchange](https://pypi.org/project/py-stackexchange/)), there are some other optimizations possible.

In your `notify` function you could use the new f-strings to simplify building the command:

```
def notify(title, subtitle, message, link):
    os.system(f"terminal-notifier -title {title!r}"
              f" -subtitle {subtitle!r} -message {message!r} -open {link!r}")
```

Note that strings on multiple lines like here are automatically joined.

Alternatively you could use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), which has a lot more advanced features, which are not needed here, though:

```
from subprocess import run

def notify(title, subtitle, message, link):
    run(["terminal-notifier", "-title", repr(title), "-subtitle", repr(subtitle),
         "-message", repr(message), "-open", repr(link)])
```

In your `fetch` function you have a possible slow-down. Since `QUE_LI` (not the most informative name, btw, should also probably be lowercase since it is not a global *constant*) is a `list`, checking `in` is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$. Just make it a `set` instead to get \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ `in`. I would also `and` the two `if` conditions. This saves one level of indentation.

Instead of using `"html.parser"`, consider using `"lxml"` (you might have to [install it first](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)). It is usually faster.

Also note that you are shadowing the built-in function `id` here and the way you call `notify` does not conform to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It took me a while to realize that the following lines are all part of the call and its keyword arguments, and not just new lines. It is arguable whether the keywords are needed here at all.

It is also unclear if `WATCHED_TAG` is supposed to be one tag or multiple tags. If it is just one, as the name suggests, then `' '.join([WATCHED_TAG])` is quite pointless, since it is just `WATCHED_TAG`. If it is multiple, then that command won't join them properly and `if WATCHED_TAG in tags` will only return true if the order of the tags is the same.

```
seen_ids = set()

def fetch():
    r = requests.get(SE_REALTIME)
    # r.raise_for_status()  # to enable failing if the request fails
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    for child in soup.find_all('div', {'data-sid': 'stackoverflow.com'}):
        question_id = child['class'][2]
        tags = child.find("span#", attrs={'class': 'realtime-tags'}).text.strip()
        if WATCHED_TAG in tags.split() and question_id not in seen_ids:
            seen_ids.add(question_id)
            question = child.find("a", attrs={'class': 'realtime-question-url realtime-title'})
            notify(f'New Question {WATCHED_TAG}', 'Stackoverflow.com',
                   question.text.strip(), question['href'])
```

Answer (score 5):

Why would you use `stackexchange.com` and only take ones with the title of `stackoverflow.com`? That's a huge waste.

You could change your url from `https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime` to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=realtime`.

However, actually visiting the website the way you are is hacky and overkill. Instead of web scraping, use the [Stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

There is no way to get a notification when a new question is posted. You will have to make a call every time you want the latest results.

**Edit:** there may be a way to get notifications, see [vogel612's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229875/get-a-notification-when-questions-get-posted/229878#comments-229878):

> there is websockets to receive notifications when a new question is
>   posted. To my knowledge these are very much undocumented and easier to
>   get access to with a userscript (which would imply changing to
>   javascript), but it's not like there's no way to receive notifications
>   from SE directly.

Comment: there is websockets to receive notifications when a new question is posted. To my knowledge these are very much undocumented and easier to get access to with a userscript (which would imply changing to javascript), but it's not like there's no way to receive notifications from SE directly.